# Cannot read property $onAuth' of with angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get my app to use firebase auth.. 
At this stage I have my login controller successful, but it logs in and the next second it's logged out.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, userAuth) {
     if ($scope.authData) {
        console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
      } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
      }
     $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.authData = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      userAuth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.loginemail, $scope.loginpassword)
      .then(function(authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
         console.log(authData);
         $location.path('/home');
         $scope.$apply(); 
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.message;
      });
    };
  });
```

I have a service where I get my firebase object:

```
.service('userAuth', ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
```

What will be the better way for authentication state so I can use it throughout my site?

I tried using the $onAuth  but i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$onAuth' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using the new Firebase (3.x.x) and the new AngularFire (2.x.x).

In that case instead of `$onAuth` you should use [`$onAuthStateChanged`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#onauthstatechangedcallback-context)

See the [migration guide](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md)